# How to mock a class, whose object created at class level of another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

For Example I have a class like this:

```
class Ex1{
    Ex2 e = new Ex2();
    Ex1(){
        System.out.println("COnstructor of Ex1");
    }
    public int m1(){
       int i = e.test();
       return i;
    }
 }

 class Ex2{
     Ex2(){
         //some code here, I dont want to execute this code
      }
     public int test(){
         return 5;
     }
 }
```

I am writting test class for `Ex1 class`, here I have to `mock Ex2 class`

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Ex1.class,Ex2.class})
class Ex1Test{

private static Ex1 ex;
private static Ex2 e;
@BeforeClass
public static void start(){
    e = mock(Ex2.class);
    PowerMock.whenNew(Ex2.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(e);
    ex1 = new Ex1();
}
```

But its not mocking `Ex2 class` object, its creating directly...

Comment: You should indent your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Could you try adding when(e.test()).thenReturn(5); after e=mock(Ex2.class); in the start method?

Comment: Yes I tried, but not working... I just modified code,, check it again

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you created **hard-to-test** code.

Yes, one can use Powermock to "solve" that problem. But thing is: you still created tightly coupled, hard-to-test production code. The simple answer is: when you have to "control" your objects, you simple don't call **new** directly in your production code.

There are two ways to prevent that:

1. You use dependency injection to simply **provide** such an object to your production code
2. You use dependency injection to provide a **factory** to your production code

When you do that, you do not need Powermock any more.

Long story short: before adding the dependency towards Powermock; watch those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79), and consider if you not using Powermock might be the better alternative for you.

Comment: it was sample code only.. In original code they created object at class level only in original code.I cant change that code, but I have to write test code for that class.

Comment: Then you hit the one and only (in my eyes) good reason to use Powermock. If you dont mind, I will keep my answer around ;-)

Comment: but That Powermock statement was not working,,, its executing constructor of 'Ex2 class '